# Can we able to launch Web browsers using calabash?

Tags: android, ios, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, calabash

I need to **minimize my app** and need to **launch a browser**(Any mobile browser/Firefox/Chrome/Safari) in iOS/Android **mobile**. If there any possible way to achieve it using **Calabash**.

Have ready to use any web drivers like Selenium / Watir.

Please provide your suggestions to overcome this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Calabash iOS, you can background the app, but you cannot interact with any applications outside of your app.

```
# send the app to the background for 5 sec
> send_app_to_background 5
```

I have heard that some people have had success using watir from within Calabash to open and interact with a web browser on the host machine.

I do not know enough about Calabash Android to comment.  I do know that the Calabash Android `app_to_background` function is not yet implemented.